# Number counter issue

Tags: javascript

I have been searching the entire day for a solution to this problem. I like [this Counter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11965561/js-counter-continuously-updating) I found on StackOverflow, but because I am inexperienced using JavaScript, I am not entirely sure how to stop it.

I figured out how to set the value and when to start counting etc, but now I want to add a maximum value. IE: If the counter reaches 20 million, then stop.

I tried the following, but it doesn't work:

```
var simplicity = formatMoney(20000000);

if (amount.innerText <= simplicity){
        function update() {
            var current = (new Date().getTime() - start)/1000*0.36+0;
            amount.innerText = formatMoney(current);
        }
    setInterval(update,1000);
}
else{
    amount.innerText = simplicity;
}
```

Comment: You are only checking your innerHTML against simplicity before your loop. You need to move that check inside your `update` function I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var max = 20000000;

var intervalId = setInterval(function () {
    var current = (new Date().getTime() - start)/1000*0.36+0;
    if (current > max) {
        amount.innerText = formatMoney(max);
        clearInterval(intervalId);
    } else {
        amount.innerText = formatMoney(current);
    }
}, 1000);
```

Use `clearInterval(id)` to stop intervals.

Comment: Updated my answer. This code should be working given `start`, `formatMoney` and `amount` are defined and valid.